# Sort data in a data frame and rank them

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
Name   Value
A.        -5
B.       100
F.         0
G.        -5
```

I want to sort the data in an ascending order and add a rank column. So I want something like this:

```
Name.      Value.      Rank
A.            -5.         1
G.            -5.         1
F.             0.         2
B.           100.         3
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution could be:

```
v1 <- order(df$Value)
data.frame(df[v1, ], rank = as.numeric(factor(df$Value[v1])))


# Name  Value rank
#1   A.    -5    1
#4   G.    -5    1
#3   F.     0    2
#2   B.   100    3
```

Sorting the dataframe with `order` and converting the sorted `Value` to `factors` and then `numeric` so that the `Value` with same value would get same rank.

Comment: I have one question. Why do we need to subset v1 from df$Value when using factor?

Comment: @Taliman `v1` is the sorted order which we are interested in. If we do not use `v1` we'll get `Value` in the same order without sorting which is -5, 100, 0, -5.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved easily with the `dplyr` package.

```
#Recreate the data
df <- read.table(text = "Name Value
A. -5
B. 100
F. 0
G. -5", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(Value) %>% mutate(Rank = dense_rank(Value))
```

The `dplyr` function reads take the data frame `df`, then arrange it by `Value`, then add a new column `Rank` which equals the dense ranking of `Value`.

Comment: Can I do it without using any package?

Comment: According to [this page](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/103) there is no R equivalent function. You may be able to do it in multiple steps beginning with `rank(df$Value, ties.method = "min")` because this leaves gaps.

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(rank(df$Value, ties.method="min")))` as one attempt

Comment: All `dense_rank` does is essentially `df <- df[order(df$Value),]; df$rank <- match(df$Value, unique(df$Value))`